# Periodic Network Timeouts

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

When streaming, gaming, surfing, etc. I lose connection every 10-20 minutes for 5 seconds or so. At first I thought it was a wireless adapter problem so I upgraded from a Belkin N150 to a TRENDnet N600 PCI card. After the problem continued to persist, I decided to try a hardwire, which didn't help either. At this point I've run out of ideas on how to fix this problem. Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use a wired Ethernet-connected client for now to keep wireless problems out of the mix.

Open up a terminal window and start a continuous once-per-second ping of your router's LAN private IP address.

Open up a second terminal window and start a continuous once-per-second ping of an IP address at your ISP or some well known, high-availability public IP address.

Leave those windows running in the background and go about your normal Internet usage. Next time you have a glitch, see if both pings stopped going through or just one of them. If you can still ping the router but you can't ping the Internet, then it means your broadband connection is screwing up, but probably not your router. If both pings go down, then it's probably your router. See if you can see evidence in your router's system log that it had some kind of a problem or auto-rebooted.